# connect to tfs with current logged in windows user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, tfs, windows-identity

I am trying to connect to tfs in a mvc application. I want to connect with the logged in windows user credentials. I tried something like

```
var tfsCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(new WindowsCredential(), true);
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfssite.com/tfs/" + Collection), tfsCredentials);
```

this doesnt return any user when i debug and always get the information based on the app pool user identity.

I also enabled windows authentication in web.config but nothing seems working.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
GT

Answer (score 3):

This way

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
  new Uri("http://tfssite.com/tfs/" + Collection),
  System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
```